# Visual Studio Nuget version history

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

When I am in Visual Studio and go into "Manage Nuget Packages" for my project, it shows which version I have installed and the latest stable version. Below that, it shows the Date Published for the new version.  Is there a way to:

1) See the Date Published for the version that I currently have installed (which is not the latest)? I'm interested in knowing how old my current version is.

2) See a complete version history with version numbers and dates?

3) View release notes for a particular version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Manage NuGet Packages UI in Visual Studio, we could not view current installed package version information. But we could view other versions release date by select the version in Version combobox.

You could view the NuGet package information from [nuget.org site](https://www.nuget.org/), where include package complete version history and the release note for every version.

Please open the Nuget.org site and search the package you want to view. On the package page, it will contains following content that you need (the screenshot shows the Bootstrap package information). You could click the version hyperlink in Version History list to view different version information.

[image]

**Please note**, the Release Notes is not shown for every packages. Because this is based on author, who release this package.